# How to render filter in index page in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I filter the index page using the filter. Then I go to the view page and come back to the index page. How can I retain the currently applied filter until the clear filter is clicked?

Can someone please help with this?
Thanks in advance.